# How to Control PanelMenu state from one page to another page?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces layout for my page where the west part is panelmenu model for navigating from one page to another page. My panelmenu is on separate(template) page.

My problem is state of the panel menu from one page to another page. I want to set the menuItem link state to be active in another page. So how to control the state of menuItem link in the panel menu model. I didn't find any action performed method for DefaultMenuItem.

Please Help!!

```
I am using
PrimeFaces 4.0 | Jboss AS 7.1.1 | Mojarra 2.1.18
Windows XP | Firefox 25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is not possible to control the default state of panelMenu.

As a temporal solution you can use Java Script to solve the problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ui-panelmenu-content").css("display","block"); //shows the menuitems
  $(".ui-panelmenu-header").addClass("ui-state-active"); //sets the submenu header to active state
  $(".ui-icon-triangle-1-e").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s"); //sets the triangle icon to "expaned" version
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution but it always expands the panelmenu links. I thought of  setting the styleClass of menulink by using actionlistener. But I didn't find any actionlistener method for DefalutMenuItem in primefaces 4.0. How to add actionlistener for DefaultMenuItem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: you need to put `stateful="true"`
and in the itemMenu set `ajax=false` `async= false` `global= false` `partialSubmit=false` `resetValue=false` `immediate=true`. That's it.